# Strange behaviour when trying to edit a comment under a nomination post

Tags: bug, comments, election

I was trying to edit the comment I posted under [this nomination post](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/7#post-2867391) in the Mathematics election. I clicked the 'edit' link at the end:

[image]

which resulted in a comment box with the text 'cancelhelp' and some misaligned links:

[image]

Upon clicking 'cancel', the comment source markdown is shown under the comment itself:

[image]

I couldn't reproduce this behaviour with another test comment, and I'm just too late now to try it with this comment in another browser. I'm using Firefox 61.0.1 on macOS 10.13.6